# NFA for $L = \{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* : \text{at least one symbol appears only once in }w \}$

Tags: automata, regular-language

> Write an NFA to recognize the language
>   $$L = \{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* :  \text{at least one symbol appears only once in }w \}.$$

I'm not quite sure how to do this question. I don't know how to keep track of the number of times each letter appears in the string.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you write $L$ as a regular expression, then draw the corresponding NFA.

Comment: In general you cannot use DFAs or NFAs to count, without limitations, the number of times a symbol occurs.  However, as pointed out by JMac31, for your question this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to keep track of the number of times a letter appears. You just need to remember if you have seen the letter or not.

For example a language in the binary case with alphabet $\{a,b\}$ that accepts a string if and only if each letter appears at least once needs 4 states $S_0, S_a, S_b$, and $S_{a,b}$ where $S_0$ is the start state and $S_{a,b}$ is the accept state. From the start state $S_0$ transition to $S_a$ on an $a$ and to $S_b$ on a $b$. When in $S_a$ loop on any $a$ and only transition to $S_{a,b}$ on a $b$. Similarly for $S_b$. Once you read $S_{a,b}$ you loop until the end of the string.

Sorry I do not have time to draw this machine. Hopefully this idea makes sense and can help you in the ternary $\{a,b,c\}$ case. Note this is different from your problem, but easier to explain with out a picture of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  An NFA which recognises all words in which $a$ occurs only once is given by the following table.
$$\matrix{&a&b&c\cr q_1&q_2&q_2&q_2\cr q_2&\hbox{none}&q_2&q_2\cr}$$
The initial state is $q_1$ and both states are accepting.  (Note that, strictly speaking, "only once" means "once or not at all".  If the question was supposed to be that at least one symbol occurs *exactly* once, make the accepting state $q_2$ only.)

If you are using the version of NFAs in which more than one initial state is permitted, you should now be able to finish the job.  Good luck!